# automorphism group of rationally connected variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $X$ be a rationally connected, smooth projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$. Then let $Aut^{0}(X)$ be the identity component of the automorphism group.

I would like to find a reference or a proof for the following fact:

**Fact:** $Aut^{0}(X)$ is a linear algebraic group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\def\Aut{\mathrm{Aut}}\def\Pic{\mathrm{Pic}}\def\PGL{\mathrm{PGL}}\def\GL{\mathrm{GL}}\def\SL{\mathrm{SL}}$
When I first read the question, I thought the request was for a reference for the fact that $\Aut^0(X)$ is an algebraic group, which is true without the hypothesis of rational connectedness. The usual source to cite for this is

*Matsusaka, T.*, [**Polarized varieties fields of moduli and generalized Kummer varieties of polarized abelian varieties**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2372821), Am. J. Math. 80, 45-82 (1958).

On a second read, I think the OP knows this and is looking for a citation for the fact that, if $X$ is rationally connected, then $\Aut^0(X)$ is a **linear** algebraic group (and not, say, an elliptic curve). I don't know a reference for this, but I can explain it. The proof falls into two parts: (1) Rationally connected implies $\Pic^0(X)$ is trivial and (2) $\Pic^0(X)$ is trivial implies that $\Aut^0(X)$ embeds in $\PGL$ of a large projective embedding. (Recall that $\PGL_n$ is a linear algebraic group. Proof: For $g \in \GL(V)$, let $g^{\otimes k}$ be the matrix by which $g$ acts on $V^{\otimes k}$. Then $\PGL_n$ embeds in $\GL_{n^n}$ by $g \mapsto g^{\otimes n}/(\det g)$.)

**If $X$ is a rationally connected, then $\Pic^0(X)$ is trivial.** From the exponential sequence $1 \to \mathbb{Z} \overset{2 \pi i}{\longrightarrow} \mathcal{O} \overset{\exp}{\longrightarrow} \mathcal{O}^{\ast} \to 1$, we identify $\Pic^0(X)$ with the cokernel of $H^1(X, \mathbb{Z}) \to H^1(X, \mathcal{O})$, so it is enough to show that $H^1(X, \mathcal{O})=0$. By symmetry of the Hodge diamond, it is equivalent to show that $H^0(X, \Omega^1)=0$.

The condition $H^0(X, \Omega^1)=0$ is a standard property of rationally connected varieties. A reference is Corollary 3.8 in Kollar's book *Rationally Connected Varieties* (1996).

I tried to write out my own proof of $H^0(X, \Omega^1)=0$ from scratch (in particular, without Kollar's Theorem 3.7) and found it harder than I expected: Here is what I came up with. Suppose that $\omega$ is a nonzero global $1$-form on $X$. By Hodge theory, $d \omega=0$. Thus, $\int \omega$ is a well-defined linear functional on $H_1(X, \mathbb{Z})$, and therefore $\int_{\gamma} \omega$ can only take countably many values as $\gamma$ ranges over $1$-cycles. If $\omega$ is nonzero, then we can find two points $p$ and $q$ and a path $\alpha$ from $p$ to $q$ where $\int_{\alpha} \omega$ is not one of these countably many values. Now, take a rational chain linking $p$ and $q$ and let $\beta$ be a path from $q$ to $p$ within this chain. Since every $1$-form on a rational curve is $0$, we have $\omega|_{\beta} =0$ and $\int_{\beta} \omega =0$. So $\int_{\alpha + \beta} \omega = \int_{\alpha} \omega$. But $\alpha+\beta$ is a closed cycle, contradicting our condition that $\int_{\alpha} \omega$ is not a value of $\int_{\gamma} \omega$ for cycles. $\square$

**$\Pic^0(X)$ is trivial implies that $\Aut^0(X)$ embeds in $\PGL$:**
Let $L$ be a very ample line bundle, so $X$ embeds naturally in $\mathbb{P}(H^0(X, L)^{\vee})$. For any $g \in \Aut(X)$, we have a natural diagram
$$\begin{matrix} 
X & \overset{g}{\longrightarrow} & X \\ 
\downarrow & & \downarrow \\
\mathbb{P}(H^0(X, g^{\ast} L)^{\vee}) & \overset{(g^{\ast})^{\vee}}{\longrightarrow} & \mathbb{P}(H^0(X, L)^{\vee}) \\
\end{matrix} .$$

Now, since $\Pic^0(X)$ is trivial, $\Pic(X)$ is discrete and $\Aut^0(X)$ acts trivially on $\Pic(X)$. So $L \cong g^{\ast} L$. This isomorphism is not unique but is unique up to multiplication by a scalar. (In general, it would be unique up to an element of $\Aut(L)$, which is to say a nonvanishing global function on $X$, but $X$ is connected and projective, so the only such functions are scalars.) Hence, the isomorphsm $\mathbb{P}(H^0(X, L)^{\vee}) \to \mathbb{P}(H^0(X, g^{\ast} L)^{\vee})$ induced by $g^{\ast} L \to L$ IS unique. Adding this to the digaram above, we get
$$\begin{matrix} 
X &=& X & \overset{g}{\longrightarrow} & X \\ 
\downarrow & & \downarrow & & \downarrow \\
\mathbb{P}(H^0(X, L)^{\vee}) & \cong & \mathbb{P}(H^0(X, g^{\ast} L)^{\vee}) & \overset{(g^{\ast})^{\vee}}{\longrightarrow} & \mathbb{P}(H^0(X, L)^{\vee}) \\
\end{matrix} .$$

The bottom maps give an action of $g$ on $\mathbb{P}(H^0(X, L)^{\vee})$ (I leave it to you to check that it is an action) and hence a map $\Aut^0(X) \to \PGL_N$. We need to check that this map is injective. Suppose that $g$ acts trivially on the bottom row. Since the vertical maps are injections, it must act trivially on the top row. But this is the definition of $g$ being trivial in $\Aut^0(X)$. $\square$

Comment: Thanks a lot! By the way, how does one see that the map $Aut^{0}(X) \rightarrow PGL_{n}$ is a morphism of algebraic groups?